# How can i get string from json response via volley

Tags: android, json

How can i get string via json object key for showing data not found,
if json array data is available, following code work perfectly. when data is not found then showing volley error like as

> com.android.volley.ClientError

```
public void posLoad(){
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    String url = getString(R.string.myPostLoad)+"01858456388";

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try{
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                String err = jsonObject.getString("message");
                if (err.equals("no")){
                    Toast.makeText(MyPosts.this,"No post found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    JSONArray jsonArrayData = jsonObject.getJSONArray("posts");

                    for (int i=0; i<jsonArrayData.length(); i++){

                        Post post = new Post();

                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArrayData.getJSONObject(i);

                        //user data
                        post.setName(jsonObject1.getString("name"));
                        post.setEmail(jsonObject1.getString("email"));
                        post.setPhoto(jsonObject1.getString("photo"));
                        postList.add(post);
                    }
                }
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(MyPosts.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    MySingleton.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}
```

(1) json response is when data not found

{"message":"no"}

(1) json response is when data found

{"posts":[{"name":"Saif ullah","email":"nzsn","photo":"01858456387.png","created_at":"2012-03-19 12:57:42","updated_at":"2012-03-19 12:57:42"}]}

server script for no data found

```
echo json_encode(array("message" => "no"));
```

from first response not getting string.
how can i solve it.....help me...

Comment: post your JSON response.

Comment: show the exception stacktrace

Comment: Edit your main post and don't post the JSON in comments.

Comment: post complete stacktrace for error

Comment: i have posted JSON response.

Answer (score 2):

You are not stooping the execution of the code when the response is no just add else after the if :

```
if (err.equals("no")){
   Toast.makeText(MyPosts.this,"No post found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
   JSONArray jsonArrayData = jsonObject.getJSONArray("posts");
   ...
}
```